# Can the prefix a- be appended to the word schismatic to form the word aschismatic, meaning the opposite of schismatic?

Tags: etymology, grammaticality, adjectives, negation, prefixes

Can the prefix *a-* be appended to the word *schismatic* to form the word *aschismatic*, meaning the opposite of *schismatic*? Both the prefix *a-* and the word *schism(atic)* seem to be of Ancient Greek origin, so from my limited understanding it appears that this could be a valid word, yet I have never seen it used.

Answer (score 1):

The [more common forms](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schismatic) are:

> ***nonschismatic***,  or 
>   nonschismatical,
>
> ***unschismatic***, or 
>   unschismatical,

(Dictionary.com)

It appears the form *[aschismatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unschismatic%2Cnonschismatic%2Caschismatic&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunschismatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonschismatic%3B%2Cc0)* has never been used.

Comment: Thank you for these forms. I am aiming to use aschismatic simply due to it containing elements of my own name. Would aschismatic be a grammatically correct version of nonschismatic or unschismatic?

Comment: @Alex -     I think  it  would be understood even though it is not or very rarely used. The prefix non- appears to be the more common between the two.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [alpha privative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_privative), which is often used to negate words of Greek origin. As *schism* is of Greek origin, it can certainly be used; and a web search does indeed throw up occurrences. As it's only used in obscure religious contexts, Google n-grams are not really a reliable source. It is, however, exceedingly rare, and a lot of the web search hits actually result from *a schismatic* run together by mistake. A cursory glance at some results only shows [one genuine (though rather tongue-in-cheek) usage](https://havenbartton.blogspot.com/). So it is a valid word, and one that is easy to understand due to its productive formation, but still rather obscure.

Comment: Yes, I did find all of the Google search results for aschismatic were due to a and schismatic being run together erroneously in religious texts. That last find though is great, thanks! I think I will be comfortable using it, but was curious about the grammaticality of the usage.

Comment: @DanHall Morphology can be taken as a part of grammar (in the broader view); it would be syntax that governs phrase structure.

Comment: @DanHall Trust me, I'm a linguist. Morphology (the study of word forms) would generally be a part of grammar, as would be syntax; diction is not a term commonly used in linguistics.

Comment: @DanHall Of course; I just wanted to clarify that I was using the terms in the linguistic meaning (rather than the general one). Saussure is these days mainly used for his theoretical foundations of linguistics, not his actual descriptions, which are somewhat antiquated. In 20 years of teaching linguistics at a well-known UK university (including Saussure's linguistic theory) I have never used 'diction', IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

We can (and often do) communicate with others using new phrases and sentences, breaking apart other phrases we've heard at some point in our life into words, moving them around, and replacing some with others we've heard. As long as the new phrase is grammatical and sensible, it works. A phrase doesn't have to have been uttered before to be "correct".

Words are altogether different. You can only break a word into morphemes to understand those that already exist. You can't reshuffle them, even if you are following rules that make sense. Your new word is an error. If you're a celebrity, you might get others to make the same error. If they keep doing it, over time your error might become a new word, but for now it's still a mistake.

So, following on @user110518's answer. No, that particular word isn't used, so the answer to your question: "Can I add a prefix to this word and make a new word", or in the comments, "is it grammatically correct" the answer is no. It's not correct because it's not (yet) a word.

Comment: It is not an error, though. The alpha privative is a productive morpheme, and thus can be added to other morphemes to form a new word. And even if neither of us has come across this particular word before, we have no difficulty understanding its meaning.

Comment: @OliverMason I disagree, especially considering nonschismatic and unschismatic are in use. I'd mark it incorrect on a paper, and I believe an editor would do the same.

Comment: @DanHall I find your answer confusing. In your first paragraph you state that "a phrase doesn't have to have been uttered before to be 'correct,'" yet in your final paragraph you state that, "it's not correct because it's not (yet) a word." These two statements appear to be in direct conflict of one another, unless I am misunderstanding your meaning.

Comment: @Alex I'm drawing a distinction between a phrase (a group of words) and a word. A phrase doesn't have to have been uttered before in order to be correct. A word does. That doesn't mean a new word is incomprehensible. It just means it's an error.

Comment: @DanHall The fact that an alternative word exists does not make it wrong, though.

Comment: @OliverMason in general, yes, but the fact that a neologism already has two words that mean the same thing as the proposed new word would make me less willing to accept it. It's the... oh, that's not the word for that... you meant "nonschismatic" or  "unschismatic".

Comment: @DanHall I see your meaning, thank you. Perhaps I mis-tagged my question and it should have been regarding morphemes, rather than grammaticality.

Comment: That is an overly prescriptive view of lexical development. Of course it is fine to use word-building rules to create new words, whether you're a celebrity or not, and they are not errors.

Comment: @OliverMason I think I would agree with you in that respect. I feel I have to qualify my agreement, though, with the fact that I am no expert in language structure, linguistics, etc. I am sufficiently comfortable with using the word now. The context will be a website name, so I think it is acceptable regardless, seeing as many websites, companies, etc use words that are not real, or are derivatives of real words. Aschismatic would be easily understood by someone who knows the word schism, whether or not the word aschismatic is technically correct or not.

Comment: @OliverMason I didn't say it was not an error if the celebrity made it, I just said it's more likely that a lot of other people would follow your lead if you were a celebrity (e.g., Shakespeare, or a Kardashian)

Comment: @Alex the context would have been helpful. You can name something whatever you'd like, and for a website or company, being new is important.

Comment: @DanHall Sorry for not including that. The full context is that my initials are A S Chism. That, combined with the intended meaning of aschismatic being non-divisive or unifying, will work really well for a name for my project. Thank you so much for your input! Very informative.

Comment: @Alex So this whole thing was an aschismatic question! :)

Comment: @Alex I think that's a great name for your website!